# RPI program not working when started with GPIO button

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, gpio

So I'm making simple sports semaphore to display results and time. I use TkInter for GUI and GPIO (physical buttons) to add scores, pause/reset scores etc...
When I start timer/program with the GPIO button other GPIO buttons don't work anymore and I can't figure why. I can't add scores, or pause timer...
If I start program with GUI button it works normally and I can add scores, pause timer with other GUI buttons. Here is the code and I think there is some problem with passing the "root".
Also, when there's GPIO button pressed it passes argument so I had to use that "smth" for functions, and when you press GUI button there's nothing to pass to functions.
So all in all, when I press GUI button to call start() it all works, when I start with GPIO button adding scores and other GPIO buttons don't work

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Tkinter as tk
import time


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) 
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) 
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) 


def fun_score1(smth):
    global score1
    score1 += 1
    label_team1['text'] = 'Team 1: ' + str(score1)

def fun_score2(smth):
    global score2
    score2 += 1
    label_team2['text'] = 'Team 2: ' + str(score2)

def start():
    global count_flag, count
    count_flag = True

    while True: 
        if count_flag == False:
            break
        # put the count value into the label
        label_time['text'] = str(count)
        # wait for 0.1 seconds
        time.sleep(0.1)
        # needed with time.sleep()
        root.update()
        # increase count
        count += 0.1

def stop(smth=1):
    global count_flag, count, score1, score2
    count_flag = False
    count = 0.0
    score1 = 0
    score2 = 0
    label_time['text'] = str(count)
    label_team1['text'] = 'Team 1: ' + str(score1)
    label_team2['text'] = 'Team 2: ' + str(score2)

def pause(smth=1):
    global count_flag
    count_flag = False

count = 0.0
score1 = 0
score2 = 0

root = tk.Tk()
# this will be a global flag
count_flag = True

# create needed widgets
label_time = tk.Label(root, text='0.0')
label_team1 = tk.Label(root, text='Team 1: ' + str(score1))
label_team2 = tk.Label(root, text='Team 2: ' + str(score2))

#btn_pause = tk.Button(root, text='Pause', command=pause)
btn_start = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start)
#btn_stop = tk.Button(root, text='Reset', command=stop)

btn_start.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
#btn_stop.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5)
#btn_pause.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)

label_time.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
label_team1.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
label_team2.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

GPIO.add_event_detect(22, GPIO.RISING, callback=start, bouncetime=300)
GPIO.add_event_detect(24, GPIO.RISING, callback=stop, bouncetime=300)
GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.RISING, callback=pause, bouncetime=300)
GPIO.add_event_detect(4, GPIO.RISING, callback=fun_score1, bouncetime=300)
GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.RISING, callback=fun_score2, bouncetime=300)


# start the event loop
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Program GUI]

Comment: Did you try adding parameter `smth=1` to `start()` function like `def start(smth=1):`.

Comment: yes, did not write it here, I tried but it doesn't help...

Comment: Is there any error shown in console when start() is triggered by GPIO?

Comment: no, there's not a single error, it gives error if I press the button without parameter smth, as you said in previous comment - def start(smth=1):

Comment: Can you show how your buttons are wired to the GPIOs?